# loop in JSON with undefined elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve the values of a json of which i do not know the number of elements.
Example:

my json can be something like

```
var json = ["fixelement1":"value1","fixelement2":"value2","fixelement3":"value3","variableelement4":"value4","variableelement5":"value5"]
```

or

```
var json =["fixelement1":"value1","fixelement2":"value2","fixelement3":"value3","variableelement7":"value7","variableelement8":"value8", "variableelementN":"valueN"]
```

the only thing that I know is that the first 3 elements are always the same.
I use .indexOf() to search a value in fixelement3. What I would like to do is, if I find the element, I would like to retrieve the name of all the following  elements (which number is variable and that are unknown) and their values.

javascript or jquery would work for me, but I have no idea..
thank you in advance!

Comment: your variable are not valid json

Comment: What you have is neither JSON nor valid JavaScript.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8312459/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var json ={
   "fixelement1":"value1",
   "fixelement2":"value2",
   "fixelement3":"value3",
   "variableelement7":"value7",
   "variableelement8":"value8", 
   "variableelementN":"valueN"
}

for(prop in json){
    console.log('key ======> value', prop, '=====>', json[prop]);
}
```

Comment: despite my poor explanation (I am nothing but a beginner) and my mistakes you 've got the point! thanks a million Aravinder!